# JPA Specification query with custom user type

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have following database tables structure.

```
 clubs 
  column_name   data_type
  id            integer
  name          character varying
  features      ARRAY
 
   
 
  user_club_memberships 
  
  column_name   data_type 
   id            integer 
   user_id       integer
   club_id       integer
```

In Java side I have following entities to map relationships.

```
@Entity(name = "Club")
  @Table(name ="clubs")
  public class Club implements Serializable {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;
  
  @Column(name ="name")
  private String name;
  
  @Column(name ="featues")
  @Type(type = "com.myproj.model.StringArrayType")
  private String [] featureArray;
  
    // getter & setter other methods 
  
  }
  
  
  public class StringArrayType implements UserType {
  
   private final int[] arrayTypes = new int[] {Types.ARRAY};

  @Override
  public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return arrayTypes;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<String[]> returnedClass() {
    return String[].class;
  }
  
   @Override
  public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
      Object owner)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException {
  
    if (names != null && names.length > 0 && rs != null && rs.getArray(names[0]) != null) {
      String[] results = (String[]) rs.getArray(names[0]).getArray();
      return results;
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
      throws HibernateException,
      SQLException {
    // setting the column with string array
    if (value != null && st != null) {
      String[] castObject = (String[]) value;
      Array array = session.connection().createArrayOf("text", castObject);
      st.setArray(index, array);
    } else {
      st.setNull(index, arrayTypes[0]);
    }
  }
  
  @Override
  public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return value == null ? null : ((String[]) value).clone();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return (Serializable) value;
  }

  @Override
  public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return cached;
  }

  @Override
  public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return original;
  }

  }



 @Table(name "user_club_memberships")
  public class UserClubMembership implements Serializable{
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;
  
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "club_id")
  private Club club;
  
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
  //getter ,setter & other methods.
  
  }
```

Now I am trying to use  JPA specification query to filter using features, user id. I have following pseudo code.

```
 public void  search(User userobj,String [] featureArr){
 Specification<UserClubMembership> specifications = Specification.where(getByUser(userobj)).and(getByFeature(featureArr));
 
      List<UserClubMembership>  results=  userclubMembershipRepository.findAll(specifications);
 }
                     
  
 private  Specification<UserClubMembership> getByUser(final User userobj){
  return(root,query,builder)-> builder.equal(root.get(UserClubMembership_.user),userObj);
 }
 
 private Specification<UserClubMembership> getByFeature (String [] featureArr) {
  return (root, query,builder) ->   {
     query.distinct(true);
     Join<UserClubMembership,Club> joinObj=root.join(UserClubMembership_.CLUB, JoinType.INNER);
     return builder.equal(joinObj.get(Club_.FEATURES_ARRAY),featureArr)
  }
 }
```

I am getting following exception when I execute the  query.

```
 ERROR 5644 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 512
```

I am using  **PostgreSQL 11.15** , **spring data jpa 2.5.7**  **hibernate core 5.4.33**